# Требуется перевод к руководству по использованию меток

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

Недавно американцы [подправили текст руководства по использованию меток](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298632/339911), а у нас слетел перевод.

> [image: howto-водство]

Comment: Масонский заговор!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перевод выполнен. Будет доступен на сайте после обновления Transifex и пересборки движка.

Получилось так:

> [image: руководство]

Если есть замечания - пишите в комментариях.

Comment: Единственное замечание: ***Метка - это ключевое слово***. Как отмечено в оригинале ***keyword or label***. Под *label*'ом тут скорее всего понимается некая маркировка. Существуют метки [tag:регулярные-выражения], [tag:разработка-игр], [tag:шаблоны-проектирования] и т.д. По своей сути - это 2 ключевых слова объединённых условно в одно. Это стоит обдумать. У самого пока вариантов нет.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev можно перевести `label` как `ярлык`. Хотя не думаю, что такое дополнение что-то улучшит.

Comment: Не всегда, к сожалению, пользователи читают подсказки до конца. Обычно останавливаются на первом предложение. Из него ясно, что это строго одно слово. Да, ниже описано, что это может быть несколько, да не все дойдут до этого...